# Why is my controller not found?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I started playing around with Web Api by creating a Web API and a Client, all worked fine until I switched from `GetAsync()` to `PostAsync()`, now I get a 404 response each time, why could this be?

**Server Side Code**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("users/verifyLoginCredentials/{username}/{password}")]
public IHttpActionResult VerifyLoginCredentials(string username, string password)
{
            var verificationResult = Models.User.VerifyLoginCredentials(username, password);
            if (verificationResult)
            {
                return Ok("Login Successful");
            }

       return BadRequest("Login Failed");
}
```

**.Net 4.5 Client Code**

```
static async Task<Uri> verifyLoginCredentials(string username, string password)
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:4685/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var value = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "username", "hello" },
       { "password", "world" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(value);
    var result = await client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials/", content);
    string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return result.Headers.Location;
}
```

Comment: Try to see in fiddler what is the excat url that you are using for the http request.

Comment: @thescion 'client.PostAsync("users/verifyLoginCredentials/{username}/{password}", content);' this managed to make it work I think, I thought I already tried this

Comment: @Aboudi  -Since you are passing the content as Body, so you should prefix `[FromBody]` in the parameter so that WebApi binds those parameter from sent request's body.

Comment: @user1672994 I see, so I can get rid of the parameters specified within the URI passed to the PostAsync() method.

Comment: Yes, those can be removed as routed parameters.

Comment: @Aboudi apologies `public IHttpActionResult VerifyLoginCredentials([FromBody]string username, [FromBody]string password)` will not work as multiple FromBody paramters can not be used in action -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @user1672994, Thanks I was wondering why it was not working.